# Unable to write script tag which includes some code in React Component

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I need some assistance regarding the following code in react project. How to write such a script inside a React component:

```
import React from 'react';

const SampleScript = ({ type, data }) => (
<script type="text/javascript">
{`
{
window.anyObject = window.anyObject || {};
anyObject.recommendationContext = {type: '${type}', 
data: ['${data}']};
}
`}
</script>
);
```

I want to write such a script in one of the .js files in my react project.

I used Helmet component of React to enclose the script tags and it did the job but I was getting some other issues with using Helmet.

I also used Safe.script which is also of React family, but scripts enclosed with Safe are not working in Internet Explorer browser.

```
import React from 'react';
import Safe from 'react-safe';

const SampleScript = ({ type, data }) => (
<Safe.script type="text/javascript">
{`
{
window.anyObject = window.anyObject || {};
anyObject.recommendationContext = {type: '${type}', 
data: ['${data}']};
}
`}
</Safe.script>
);
```

```
import React from 'react';
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';

const SampleScript = ({ type, data }) => (
<Helmet>
<script type="text/javascript">
{`
{
window.anyObject = window.anyObject || {};
anyObject.recommendationContext = {type: '${type}', 
data: ['${data}']};
}
`}
</script>
</Helmet>
);
```

Comment: Look for `type`, change the name, it might name overridding issue

Comment: hi Ashish, thanks for your reply. I was wondering how this type of script( which has some code inside it) can be written in a react component without using Helmet or Safe.script tags. Because I am getting errors in my editor while writing such a script.

Answer (score 0):

JSX is not a perfect place for javascript code (you can use js expressions) - component will be translated into function.

Why not use class component/lifecycle methods?

```
componentDidMount () {
    window.anyObject = window.anyObject || {};
    anyObject.recommendationContext = {
        type: '${this.props.type}', 
        data: ['${this.props.data}']
    };    
}
```